# Running process also if the app is closed

Tags: android, multithreading, process

i'm making an app that needs to check if a file exist every, let's say, 10 seconds. And then send a message if there's written "SEND" in the file, otherwise do nothing.
How could i create a thread/process that will check every 10 seconds if there's the file, even if i close the app? Is it possible? 
This is my code:

```
public class BootListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public BootListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, FileCheckerService.class));
    }
}


public class FileCheckerService extends Service {
    public FileCheckerService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SmsManager newSms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                newSms.sendTextMessage(
                        "+39334659348",
                        null,
                        "TRY",
                        null,
                        null);
            }
        };

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 20000);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        reader.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a service. read more about correct way of using a service:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a service with application context with overding  `startCommand` returning `Service.start_sticky` flag and have thread  in side in which set while loop like below

```
while(true)
 {
    yourThreadReference.sleep(10000); // this is 10 seconds
    // do your work  
 }
```

Comment: I've tried it, and it works just as long as the app is alive. As soon as i close the app, it stops sending sms..

Comment: I think your using activity context not application context. use android manifest.xml for broadcast registration

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't understand, can you make an example code? Why should i use a broadcastreceiver?

Comment: as soon as boot completed the you need to catch boot intent and so its  needed,in the mean while running thread will take care of the service to  be running all the time so the app process will also will be running